# PowerBI & DAX: How could I have a measure be plotted on a graph following a custom rule?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with these columns:

| Event Table |
| --- |
| Event ID |
| Event Month |
| Event Year |
| Event Type |
| Event Total Hours |

I have this measure referring to this table :

```
Frequency Rate = IF(AVERAGE(Event[Event Total Hours])<>BLANK(),
 10^6*(CALCULATE(COUNT(Event[Event ID]),
FILTER(Event,Event[Event Type]="Type A"))
/AVERAGE(Event[Event Total Hours]),BLANK())
```

When I plot this on a graph using Event Month and Event Year as the X axis, I naturally get something like this:

[image: Event Measure Plotted]

Up to here, everything is working as expected.

For exemple, in the graph for 2022-09, I get a value of about 6. This corresponds to Events that happened that month and that month only.

What I need help with is that I need this measure to always span over its last 12 months.
I need for the value for 2022-09 to apply the measure for all events that happened between 2021-09 up to 2022-09.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do such a thing. Any help is **greatly** appreciated ! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest your measure inside a CALCULATE(...,DATESINPERIOD()) function.

```
CALCULATE(
    /*existing expression*/,
    DATESINPERIOD( 'Calendar'[Date], LASTDATE( 'Calendar'[Date] ), -12, MONTH )
)
```

This requires a related Calendar table to work. It evaluates the last date in current context, and evaluates the entire expression over the preceding 12 months.